G-suite seems to be creating Content Security Policy blocking data source
My school uses G-Suite for Education with a custom domain for our school, and all our users are logged into chrome using accounts like "bob.smith@ourschool.org".
A member of my administration is trying to use the website app.asana.com. This web app gets data from another data source at the url asana.s3.amazonaws.com.
When a user logged into chrome using our school domain attempts to log in with Google, we get a 500 internal server error saying 'Content Security Policy of your site blocks some resources'. Looking at the Javascript console, I see the following message listing the CSP that's blocking the site:

With some other sites listed down below, which comes from apps I've permitted in Google Admin. As you can see, requests to asana.com and various of its subdomains are allowed. However, the requests to asana.s3.amazonaws.com aren't included, so they are blocked and the site doesn't work.
I know that this CSP is being injected by Google Suite because when I try to join asana.com with a personal (non-school) Google account I have no problem.
What I can't figure out is how to tell Google to permit the requests to asana.s3.amazonaws.com in the Content Security Policy that it's injecting in the site. How can I make it so members of my Google organization can use this site?
